# LDAP 2.5 breaks SQL Server on Debian 12

Tags: sqlserver

Resterted due to power cut and now SQL Server isn't starting because

```
/opt/mssql/bin/sqlservr: error while loading shared libraries: liblber-2.4.so.2: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

I found the files in `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu` and tried creating symlinks from the files SQL Server wants to the files that exit but it isn't fooled:

```
/opt/mssql/bin/sqlservr: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libldap_r-2.4.so.2: version `OPENLDAP_2.4_2' not found (required by /opt/mssql/bin/sqlservr)
```

Seems that I have LDAP libraries version 2.5 installed and SQL Server requires 2.4

```
# apt show libldap-common
Package: libldap-common
Version: 2.5.13+dfsg-5
Priority: optional
Section: libs
Source: openldap
Maintainer: Debian OpenLDAP Maintainers <pkg-openldap-devel@lists.alioth.debian.org>
Installed-Size: 94.2 kB
Replaces: libldap-2.4-2 (<< 2.4.44+dfsg-1)
Homepage: https://www.openldap.org/
Tag: role::shared-lib
Download-Size: 29.3 kB
APT-Manual-Installed: yes
APT-Sources: http://mirror.ox.ac.uk/debian bookworm/main amd64 Packages
Description: OpenLDAP common files for libraries
 These are common files for the run-time libraries for the OpenLDAP
 (Lightweight Directory Access Protocol) servers and clients.
```

I *guess* a possible fix is to downgrade -- is that possible? I can't see any other versions available

```
# apt list -a libldap-common
Listing... Done
libldap-common/stable,stable,now 2.5.13+dfsg-5 all [installed]
```

This seems to be the culprit:

```
# grep ldap /var/log/dpkg.log
2023-08-21 18:50:42 status installed libldap-2.4-2:amd64 2.4.57+dfsg-3+deb11u1
2023-08-21 18:50:42 remove libldap-2.4-2:amd64 2.4.57+dfsg-3+deb11u1 <none>
2023-08-21 18:50:42 status half-configured libldap-2.4-2:amd64 2.4.57+dfsg-3+deb11u1
2023-08-21 18:50:42 status half-installed libldap-2.4-2:amd64 2.4.57+dfsg-3+deb11u1
2023-08-21 18:50:42 status config-files libldap-2.4-2:amd64 2.4.57+dfsg-3+deb11u1
2023-08-21 18:50:42 status not-installed libldap-2.4-2:amd64 <none>
2023-08-27 10:20:03 install libldap-dev:amd64 <none> 2.5.13+dfsg-5
2023-08-27 10:20:03 status half-installed libldap-dev:amd64 2.5.13+dfsg-5
2023-08-27 10:20:03 status unpacked libldap-dev:amd64 2.5.13+dfsg-5
2023-08-27 10:20:03 configure libldap-dev:amd64 2.5.13+dfsg-5 <none>
2023-08-27 10:20:03 status unpacked libldap-dev:amd64 2.5.13+dfsg-5
2023-08-27 10:20:03 status half-configured libldap-dev:amd64 2.5.13+dfsg-5
2023-08-27 10:20:03 status installed libldap-dev:amd64 2.5.13+dfsg-5
2023-08-27 10:23:13 install ldap-utils:amd64 <none> 2.5.13+dfsg-5
2023-08-27 10:23:13 status half-installed ldap-utils:amd64 2.5.13+dfsg-5
2023-08-27 10:23:13 status unpacked ldap-utils:amd64 2.5.13+dfsg-5
2023-08-27 10:23:13 configure ldap-utils:amd64 2.5.13+dfsg-5 <none>
2023-08-27 10:23:13 status unpacked ldap-utils:amd64 2.5.13+dfsg-5
2023-08-27 10:23:13 status half-configured ldap-utils:amd64 2.5.13+dfsg-5
2023-08-27 10:23:13 status installed ldap-utils:amd64 2.5.13+dfsg-5
```

Can it be undone?

**Update**

Same problem on Ubuntu 22.04.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot just drop in different versions of libraries; that's not how binaries work.

So, sqlservr is a proprietary thing, right? It needs to bring all the libraries it needs then. If it depends on a system-supplied library, the author (microsoft) needs to make sure it's being kept in steplock with upstream.

So, since Microsoft seems not to be doing that, you cannot update a system that you installed mssql on arbitrarily. Open a support case with Microsoft, or if you haven't already, install the latest version of mssql.

In the meantime, the usual solution is just to put up a container with a definitely, positively supported platform up, install nothing but mssql in there, import the existing data as volumes into that container, export network ports and/or UNIX sockets used to communicate with the database and run it on the same machine as before.

> Can it be undone?

I don't know – only if there's still package files for all the old versions of software that you'll also need to downgrade when you downgrade ldap. It's probably the worse solution. But you do have backups of your database server of all things, don't you?

Comment: Here's what Microsoft tells about Debian: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/linux/sql-server-linux-setup?view=sql-server-ver16#supportedplatforms : nothing. Ubuntu 22.04 is written as preview.

Comment: yeah, so, server runs on unsupported operating system, same OS gets updated – and the server breaks; so far, not too surprising!

Answer (score 0):

This got it running:

```
# wget http://ftp.uk.debian.org/debian/pool/main/o/openldap/libldap-2.4-2_2.4.57+dfsg-3+deb11u1_amd64.deb
# apt install ./libldap-2.4-2_2.4.57+dfsg-3+deb11u1_amd64.deb
```

Comment: You didn't validate the *HTTP* download, while it would have been easy to do so by putting back the bullseye repository.

Comment: I have no idea what that means.